# Merge a list of maps in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to write a function that can merge a list of maps where the return value:

1. contains no duplicate key/value pairs
2. groups by key - for example, when there are multiple entries for the same key, all values for that key are combined as List
3. all other values are String

I've gotten this far:

```
fun mergeMaps(maps: List<Map<String, *>>): Map<String, *> {
      val mergedMap =
          maps.reduce { acc, map ->
              (acc.asSequence() + map.asSequence()).distinct().groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
          }
      return mergedMap.entries.fold(mutableMapOf<String, Any>()) { acc, entry ->
          val entryValue = entry.value as List<String>
          val key = entry.key
          val value = if (entryValue.size > 1) entryValue else entryValue.first()
          if (acc.containsKey(key)) {
              when (acc[key]) {
                  is String -> {
                      acc[key] = listOf(acc[key], value)
                  }
                  else -> {
                      acc[key] = (acc[key] as List<String>) + value
                  }
              }
          } else acc[key] = value
          acc
      }
  }
```

but I am struggling to get the function to handle existing list values.

```
val map1 = mapOf("foo" to "bar", "test" to "test-value", "arrayTest" to listOf("foo", "bar"))
val map2 = mapOf("biz" to "buz", "test" to "something-else", "arrayTest" to "baz")

val mergedMaps = mergeMaps(listOf(map1, map2))
```

yields

```
{foo=bar, test=[test-value, something-else], arrayTest=[[foo, bar], baz], biz=buz}
```

when I expect it to be:

```
{foo=bar, test=[test-value, something-else], arrayTest=[foo, bar, baz], biz=buz}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Why do you want a Map where some of the values are Lists, and others are Strings? That has a strong code smell to me… (It won't be type-safe, for one thing, so whatever is using the result will need to type-check every access.) Have you considered making it a Map of Lists, even if some of those Lists have only one item?

Comment: I agree, it's not the safest approach. 
I have considered a map of lists, which would be the easiest option however, it's not suitable for this particular use case. The intention is to serialise the merged maps to JSON and include it as part of a response.

Comment: Your question is a fun code challenge to answer, but I think you should actually re-submit your question based on what you're trying to solve (convert data to JSON) rather than how to fix your current solution https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: "_I have considered a map of lists...serialise the merged maps to JSON_" There's nothing in the JSON spec against serializing an one-element list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simpler strategy is to first add everything into a Map with List values. I would expect this to more typically be the end-goal since it would be usable without casts, but assuming you have a use case that needs it the way you described, you can then replace the lists that have only one item using `mapValues`.

```
fun mergeMaps(maps: List<Map<String, *>>): Map<String, *> {
    return maps.fold(mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Any?>>()) { outMap, map ->
        for ((key, value) in map) {
            val outList = outMap.getOrPut(key, ::mutableListOf)
            if (value is List<*>) outList.addAll(value) else outList.add(value)
        }
        outMap
    }.mapValues { (_, value) -> if (value.size == 1) value.first() else value }
}
```

This is also written in a way where the value types can be anything besides List (not just String).

Comment: This is the only way to get what OP wants, because until you merge all the maps, you won't know how many times a key appears, so you've to further post process the merged map. I suggested the same in my answer, albeit with more details than yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun merge(src: Map<String, Any>, dest: MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>) {
    src.forEach { k, v ->
        val newVal = dest.getOrPut(k) { mutableListOf<String>() }
        if (v is List<*>) newVal.addAll(v as List<String>)
        else newVal.add(v.toString())
    }
}

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    val map1 = mapOf("foo" to "bar", "test" to "test-value", "arrayTest" to listOf("foo", "bar"))
    val map2 = mapOf("biz" to "buz", "test" to "something-else", "arrayTest" to "baz")

    val mergedMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()
    merge(map1, mergedMap)
    merge(map2, mergedMap)
    val map3 = mergedMap.mapValues {
        if (it.value.size == 1) it.value.first() else it.value
    }
    print(map3)
}
```

> {foo=bar, test=[test-value, something-else], arrayTest=[foo, bar,
> baz], biz=buz}

This does what you asked for, but makes no sense because it treats Kotlin like Python. The problem is until you merge all the maps, you won't know how many times a key appears, so you've to further post process the merged map.

You mentioned in a comment about converting to JSON, you can still do that if your merged map is type `String, List<String>`. There's nothing in the JSON spec against an one-element list.